# C++ overloading + operator runs into Problem with Constants

Tags: c++, oop, constants, operator-overloading

I defined a Vec2 object that should represent a 2d-vector. I tried to overload the + operator to implement vectoraddition but I get following error in Line 40:

```
error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'const Vec2' and 'const Vec2')
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Vec2 {
private:
    double X;
    double Y;
public:
    Vec2(double x, double y){
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

double getX() const {
    return X;
}

double getY() const {
    return Y;
}

Vec2 operator+(Vec2 v ){
    Vec2 res(v.getX()+X, v.getY()+Y);
    return res;
}
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& s , const Vec2& my_vec)
{
s << " ( "<< my_vec.getX()<< " , "<< my_vec.getY() <<" ) " ;
return s ;
}

int main()
{
    Vec2 const a(3,4);      cout << a << endl;
    Vec2 const b(3,4);      cout << b << endl;

    Vec2 c(a+b);       cout << c << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Interestingly when you remove the "const" keyword from a in line 37 everything works, but I don't wan't to fix the error by changing the content of the main function.
I am new to operator overloading, so thanks for the help.

Comment: Your `operator+` should be `const` as well. (It doesn't change the contents of `this`.)

Comment: O.T.: Actually, you could implement the `operator+` as a free-standing operator (similar like you did with `operator<<`). Free-standing functions (and operators) should be preferred over member functions when possible.

Comment: FYI: [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/7478597)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left operand, `a`, is `const` but your `operator+` is not `const` qualified.

You simply need to make it so. Also, instead of taking the right operand, `b`, by value, you can (optionally) take it by `const` reference:

```cpp
Vec2 operator+(const Vec2& v) const {
//                            ^^^^^
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qav3xGjq3)

---

An alternative is to only define `operator+=` as a member function and then to make `operator+` a free function:

```cpp
class Vec2 {
public:
//...
    Vec2& operator+=(const Vec2& v) { // this changes *this, so not const qual.
        X += v.X;
        Y += v.Y;
        return *this;
    }
};

Vec2 operator+(const Vec2& lhs, const Vec2& rhs) {
    Vec2 result(lhs);
    result += rhs;     // uses the member function operator+=
    return result;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E9ErWxxG5)

---

Alternatively:

```cpp
Vec2 operator+(Vec2 lhs, const Vec2& rhs) {
    return lhs += rhs; // uses the member function operator+=
}
```

Comment: The link I provided above used a nice trick - giving `lhs` by value: `Vec2 operator+(Vec2 lhs, const Vec2& rhs) { return lhs += rhs; }` ;-)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Yeah, it's nice but doesn't play nice with NRVO so I don't think one will gain anything. It'll force a creation of a `Vec3` but it can't `NRVO` it. One optimization would be to make sure RVO is in effect and `return {lhs.X+rhs.X, lhs.Y+rhs.Y};`

Comment: @TedLyngmo: The advantage is that it *doesn't* force the creation of a `Vec2`.  In the case of `Vec2(6, 7) + Vec2(8, 9)`, it can modify the lhs directly (since its an Rvalue) instead of making a new instance. For this `Vec2`, that's not really an advantage, but for classes with owning pointers internally, it can be a big improvement.

Comment: @MooingDuck If we take `lhs` by-value, we have forced a copy/move construction of a `Vec2` there. In this case, a copy. This `Vec2` can't be NRVO'd., but `lhs += rhs` will be RVO'd. If we instead take it by `const&` and create a named variable, we copy construct one instance and if all paths leads to `return result;` it'lll most likely be NRVO'd. Hmm, yes, perhaps it is cheaper to take it by value after all. In this case we could force RVO by `return {lhs.X+rhs.X, lhs.Y+rhs.Y};` though. :)

Comment: @MooingDuck I changed my answer to only create 3 instances (originally, it created 4) and added the alternative taking it by value at the bottom,. The alternative creates 4 instances and unfortunately, I wasn't able to make the alternative only create 3.